# How to format date when I load data from google-app-engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, format, load

I use `remote_api` to load data from Google App Engine.

```
appcfg.py download_data --config_file=helloworld/GreetingLoad.py --filename=a.csv  --kind=Greeting helloworld
```

The setting is:

```
class AlbumExporter(bulkloader.Exporter):
    def __init__(self):
        bulkloader.Exporter.__init__(self, 'Greeting',
                                     [('author', str, None),
                                      ('content', str, None),
                                      ('date', str, None),
                                     ])

exporters = [AlbumExporter]
```

And I download `a.csv`. The date is not readable.

How to get the full date?

I changed this:

```
class AlbumExporter(bulkloader.Exporter):
    def __init__(self):
        bulkloader.Exporter.__init__(self, 'Greeting',
                                     [('author', str, None),
                                      ('content', str, None),
                                      ('date', lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y').date(), None),
                                     ])

exporters = [AlbumExporter]
```

However, I am still getting an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're getting a truncation at the space in the third column when you say

```
('date', str, None),
```

(the other attempt is clearly wrong because you're getting a `datetime` and you can't `strptime` *that*!-).  If you want the date as a string, try:

```
('date', lambda dt: str(dt.date()), None),
```

or, change `strptime` to `strftime` in your second attempt.  Mnemonic: the `f` in `strftime` stands for **f**ormat: take a datetime and format it to a string; the `p` in `strptime` stands for **p**arse: take a string and make a datetime out of it.  They're old names, coming from the standard library for ANSI C (and even-earlier influences on it)...